# NOSQL Database for Hight read concurrency

Tags: database, nosql

Hi I am using ldap to store user configuation, when i started i have small amount of data now it increased to more than 20 million records.

Now I face the performance issue, I preferred ldap beacuse user configuration are less updated  compare to read and search operation.

I want to replace the ldap with  NOSQL db which will provide me 20000/sec read operation for more than 50 millions record.

Data in ldap  is User info , credentials and user specific settings, issue arise because of all-ids. I have indexed data based on First name , last name, Sun ldap did well when i have lesssa data around 500K, when My data incarsed to around 5 million then i face problem for searching that , search is not indexed , later i found issue is regarding all-ids , e.g. Chavan is very comman surname in india, when it appear in more than all-id-threshold prpperty , then my seach always failed , I increased all-id threshold many time but it has performance issue. so i want to get read ldap and use nosql db

Comment: Could you describe your data. There are many NoSQL technologies that are very different to the conventional "NoSQL" that people think of. neo4j comes to mind, being a graph database is very different to a column store or document database e.g.

Answer (score 0):

What DB you want to use? In Mongo, for example, you can use [sharding](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/) for some load balancing.
Also, switching to NoSQL should be considered, coz it's *very* depends on the application logic.

Comment: Data is User info and credentials and user specific settings,

Comment: Data is User info and credentials and user specific settings, it arise because of all-ids. I have indexed data based on First name , last name, Sun ldap did well when i have lesssa data around 500K, when My data incarsed to around 5 million then i face problem for searching that , search is not indexed , later i found issue is regarding all-ids , e.g. Chavan is very comman surname in india, when it appear in more than all-id-threshold prpperty , then my seach always failed , I increased all-id threshold many time but it has performance issue. so i want to get read out this issue

Comment: You may take a peek on performance with same data using Mongo (or amazon DynamoDB or something else you choose) and compare results. I have no experience with ldap so can't say something specific.